# Should you shuffle the input for a word2vec model before or after assigning negative context pairs for each target word?

Tags: python, keras, word2vec

I'm working on a word2vec with negative sampling implementation using python and tensorflow+keras. The initial input for the script is a list of positive target-word pairs, which is processed via looping through them and assigning a number of negative examples to each, then the positive + k negative samples are appended in the corresponding order to a new list. That list is later (after a few adjustments) passed to a keras model.fit():

```
        model.fit([data[:, 0], data[:, 1]], data[:, 2], 
                  batch_size = numof_positives * (numof_negatives + 1))
```

I looked through some examples, and from what I understand, the batches passed to the neural network should contain the negative context words of those positives that are present in the batch, meaning that shuffling of the data should take place **before** assigning the negatives. On the other hand, I did not realize that keras' model.fit() has its shuffle argument on True by default, so first it was run with the data being shuffled **after** the assignment as well. Now that I've added shuffle=False, it seems like it affected the quality of the resulting embedding vectors negatively. Can that be the case? Where should the input be shuffled? What are the implications of passing completely randomly ordered data vs ordered batches?

I may have a few trust issues with the shuffle argument of keras' model.fit(), after experiencing this [bug regarding shuffle='batch'](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15846) first hand.

Answer (score 1):

The value of shuffling with respect to word2vec training (that I'm familiar with) is to avoid cases where all examples of a word, or all similar senses, are clumped together in one range of the training data. (You don't want th model to get really good at those examples where a word/sense is overrepresented... only to then have that overly-specialized performance to be lost when a long run of samples where those same words/senses are completely unrepresented.)

That's something you can achieve with a corpus-shuffle before any batch-shuffle – which might separately bring its own benefits, for similar reasons, by achieving better interleaving of contrasting microexamples.

The word2vec implementations I know tend to do the backprop-updates of a positive-example closely-alongside the corresponding N synthetic negative-examples from the same context. That is, no extra shuffling will move them further from each other.

But it's not impossible further shuffling could help! So I'd not express any opinion on what theoretically "should" happen, compared to any empirical observations, of tradeoffs seen in real runs. (Do what works best!)

(Alternatively, if the actual goal is perfectly-reproducing some other implementation's choices, then you'd mainly want to mimic its actual code, and verify by comparing quantitative results on same-data/same-evaluation tasks.)

Comment: I was afraid of the usual answer, that my ML questions get, which is: depends on the task, you should test it. Anyway, this somewhat reassures me, that using the fully shuffled data is not that bad. Although its mathematical implications are still a mystery to me.